# installed tailwind css v2, where did I went wrong?

Tags: reactjs, web, tailwind-css, web-frontend

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHSYH.png)I am trying to configure/integrate/use the tailwind css version 2 with reactjs using the official documentation of tailwind-css version.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Craco, but two things I'd double-check. 1) Did you run `npm install` (or equivalent for `yarn` and `pnpm`)? 2) It looks like your package.json file is not in the same folder as your craco.config.js file. Is this normal?

Also, if you can, I'd recommend TailwindCSS v3. Won't solve this problem, but in general it's a huge improvement over v2.

Comment: check tailwind guide to install tailwind with react it's straightforward https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app